# How to get killall on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, kill

On Cygwin, I can access `kill` from bash, but when I try to execute `killall`, I get an error message saying “not available”.

How do I get `killall` on Cygwin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the package search to locate the package with `killall`

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=bin%2Fkillall&arch=x86_64

> Search Results  Found 5 matches for bin/killall
>
> ```
> busybox-1.23.2-1 - busybox: Tiny utilities in a single executable (installed binaries and support files)
> psmisc-debuginfo-22.20-1 - psmisc-debuginfo: Debug info for psmisc (installed binaries and support files)
> psmisc-22.20-1 - psmisc: Utilities for managing processes on your system (installed binaries and support files)
> sysvinit-debuginfo-2.86-1 - sysvinit-debuginfo: Debug info for sysvinit (installed binaries and support files)
> sysvinit-2.86-1 - sysvinit: A System-V Init Clone (installed binaries and support files)
> ```

psmisc is the one you need.

Comment: `psmisc` is the right answer but the search link for `bin/killall` does not work, nor does entering it in the search box. Note that searching for killall in `setup-x86_64.exe` does not help either

Comment: @MiserableVariable There is problem in the web interface after the server upgrade. Put the value directly in the URL https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=bin/killall&arch=x86_64

Comment: I made the comment in case someone else gets confused like me. But with you explanation it will help me find other stuff :) Thanks.

Comment: the web search is now working again correctly

Answer (score 6):

Install the `psmisc` package using Cygwin Setup (which apparently does not get installed by default). This will give you the `killall` command.

Comment: `The Psmisc package contains three programs which help manage the /proc directory. Installed programs: fuser, killall and pstree`